# How to give a response based on right answers in a quiz

Tags: python, if-statement

I have created a quiz but I am struggling with the last part of the code.

```
if answer_counter <=5:
    print 'Oh dear you didn\'t do so well! Try harder next time.'
if answer_counter 6 or 7 or 8 or 9 or 10:
    print 'Not so bad! you could do better!'
if answer_counter >=11:
    print 'Brilliant you did pretty well!'
```

The problem I am having is the middle if argument, I initially tried if answer_counter >=6 and <=10: But that didn't seem to work, I then tried (6,10) so the or statement was my last try and I can't seem to find an answer!

Thanks again advance for your help

Comment: Try using a switch case for such problems, using if else would help you too

Comment: Is this Python? Please tag your question with the language in question

Comment: Sorry, this is python, still confused by how the site works. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try nested if else:

```
if answer_count <=5:
    #do something
elif answer_count >=6 and answer_count <=10:
    #do somethang
else:
    #do somethung
```

Comment: Brilliant this worked perfectly (It seems so obvious when you look at it as well!) Thanks to the other comments and this answer. the solution was for anyone else who might be reading and need help.
    if answer <=5: (do something)
    elif answer <=10: (do something)
    else: (whatever else)
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Mention not :))))))))))